# exec command doesn't work with variables added, but works without variables variables added

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

I'm trying to execute python file made by [CaryKH](https://github.com/carykh) called `jumpcutter.py` using child process

This is a working function, where the exec command does work:

```
function executePython(){

  const { exec } = require('child_process');
  const path = require('path');
  var input = document.getElementById('input').value
  var output = document.getElementById('output').value
  var silent = document.getElementById('silent').value
  var sounded = document.getElementById('sounded').value
  var margin = document.getElementById('margin').value
  alert(input)

  exec('python jumpcutter.py --input_file wow.mp4 --output_file wowcut.mp4 --silent_speed 999999 --sounded_speed 1 --frame_margin 1')
}
```

However, when I do this:

```
exec('python jumpcutter.py --input_file ' +input ' --output_file ' +output ' --silent_speed ' +silent ' --sounded_speed ' +sounded ' --frame_margin ' +margin)
```

the code doesn't work entirely, so even the alert no longer works, even though it did prior.
I have already tried to store the console command in a variable called `text` but to no prevail.

Thank you in advance for any assistance :)

Answer (score 1):

the string concatenate is wrong

to concatenate multiple strings into one the syntax is:

```
string1 + string2 + string3 + string4 + ....
```

so your code should be like this:

```
exec('python jumpcutter.py --input_file ' + input +' --output_file ' +output+ ' --silent_speed ' +silent+ ' --sounded_speed ' +sounded+ ' --frame_margin ' +margin)
```

Comment: I just realised this and was about to answer, it was a very silly mistake and it shouldn't have happened if I payed more attention. Regardless than youo for answering and I will be sure to remember this for later!